# SQL query to merge 2 identical tables with distinct

Tags: sql, merge, distinct

i want to merge 2 identicals tables into one table and distinct the users.
The 2 tables look like that :

```
Table1
**************
id, user, total
1, 1, 7
2, 2, 10
3, 3, 14


Table2
**************
id, user, total
1, 1, 4
2, 2, 7
3, 3, 3
```

I want to have this result :

```
user, total1, total2
1, 7, 4
2, 10, 7
3, 14, 3
```

How the SQL query should look ?

Comment: Does every user have exactly one record in `Table1` and exactly one record in `Table2`? Or are there some users who have no records in one of the tables? Or who have *multiple* record in one of the tables? If so, can you indicate what your result-set would look like in such a case?

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Comment: Removed two unnecessary tags (`query` is not needed: the `sql` tag implies a SQL query; `table` was misplaced: your question isn't exploring the table as a data structure). That gives room for a tag or tags specifying the SQL product you are using, as suggested by @bluefeet (please do consider adding one).

Answer (score 4):

You will want to `JOIN` the tables on the `user` column:

```
select t1.user,
  t1.total,
  t2.total as total2
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
  on t1.user = t2.user
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d62fa/2)

If you need help learning `JOIN` syntax, here is a great [visual explanation of JOINs](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) (written by [Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood)).

The `INNER JOIN` syntax will return all rows that match between both tables.

If you want to add another table, then you will just include another `JOIN`.  Based on your comment you would use:

```
select t1.user,
  t1.total,
  t2.total as total2,
  t3.department
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
  on t1.user = t2.user
inner join table3 t3
  on t1.user = t3.user
```

Comment: And if I would like to add a third table and link the user column to the other 2 and get all users in department 4.
The third table look like this :
Table 3
*****************
user fname lname department
1 Joe Doe 4
2 John Smith 6
3 Mike Dewsky 4

Comment: @user1810401 You will just add another join to the query, see my edit. :)